# NonLinearFit with data

Tags: fitting

i've data looking like this:

```
ListPlot[data]
```

[image: Plot One]

Now I want to make a NonLinearFit

```
fit = NonlinearModelFit[data, a*Sin[b*t], {a, b}, t]
Plot[fit[t], {t, 0, 20}]
```

But the Plot looks like this:

[image: Plot2]

Whats the reason why there is a wrong Plot?

Comment: Try initial values for the constants.

Comment: how do i do this?

Comment: @dnrhead Look up the [documentation for `NonlinearModelFit`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NonlinearModelFit.html); the fourth bullet in "Details and Options" shows how to specify a starting value for the parameters.

Comment: Thank you, now it's working. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a case that you gotta have good starting values.  A contour plot of the root mean square (the function that is essentially minimized) shows how the algorithm can get into trouble with bad starting values.)

```
(* Generate some data *)
data = Table[{x/10., 0.8 Sin[0.645 x/10]}, {x, 0, 200}];

(* Default starting values of 1 *)
badfit = NonlinearModelFit[data, a Sin[b t], {a, b}, t]

(* Better starting values *)
goodfit = NonlinearModelFit[data, a Sin[b t], {{a, .6}, {b, 0.6}}, t]

(* Function that determines the root mean square error *)
n = Length[data];
rmse[aa_, bb_] := Sqrt[Total[(data[[All, 2]] - aa Sin[bb data[[All, 1]]])^2/(n - 2)]]

(* Show contour plot for values of a and b and estimates *)
Show[ContourPlot[rmse[a, b], {a, 0, 1.5}, {b, 0.1, 1.5}, 
  FrameLabel -> (Style[#, Bold, Large] & ) /@ {"a", "b"}],
 ListPlot[{{a, b}} /. badfit["BestFitParameters"], PlotStyle -> {Red, PointSize[0.02]}],
 ListPlot[{{a, b}} /. goodfit["BestFitParameters"], PlotStyle -> {Green, PointSize[0.02]}]]
```

[image: Contour plot of root mean square error]

The red dot is the result of the default starting values and the green is with better starting values.

One can see that the algorithm might not travel towards the solution because of the nature of the contour plot if one starts too far away.

Comment: Yes, very interesting.  Good to know.

Comment: @ChrisDegnen And it's certainly not restricted to *Mathematica*.  R, SAS, Minitab, you name it have similar issues.  It's real hard (if not impossible) to write a completely robust optimization routine.

Comment: @JimBaldwin wonderful avoiding the 'badlands'  for ['hic sunt dracones'](https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSYBs4Rku-zO78nOuhZUAsXlIiaUqNZFg8CmZPjIYyfstpp2gZ3sg) :)