# Fit exponentially decreasing oscillation

Tags: fitting

It is a simple fit I would like mathematica to do: Fitting a set of experimentally obtained data points with an exponentially decreasing cosine function.

```
 datafit = Table[data3[[i, 2]], {i, 1, Length[data3]}];
 tab = Table[Sin[i], {i, 0.01, 100, 0.01}];
 model = Cos[a*x] Exp[b*x];
 fit = FindFit[datafit, model, {{a, 100}, {b, -10}}, x]

 Show[ListLinePlot[data3, PlotStyle -> Red], 
 Plot[{Evaluate[model /. fit]}, {x, 0, 0.6}]
```

This should give me the fit, but instead completely wrong values are found for the parameters, even when I adjusted the starting values.

The file can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xufd736fburdq8a/norm.dat?dl=0) (Dropbox).

OutPut:

[image: Failed-Fit. Blue: "Fit", Red:data]

With the blue "Fit" and the data in red.

I hope somebody finds my mistake or can explain why Mathematica is doing this!

EDIT:
For a=145 and b=-2.8 I get the following result:

[image]

Which shows, that at least the initial values I have chosen are somewhat resonable.

Comment: Your dropbox file doesn't load for me. However, odds are you just have to specify initial values.

Comment: First plot the model with your starting values against the data and make sure that you've got at least the frequency approximately correct.

Comment: @Feyre thanks for your comment, I did specify the initial values (added a picture), but somehow Mathematica does not find the best values obviously. The file is a .dat-file, which is the reason that is not available for a priview in your browser, but can be imported to Matematica. Use this Link:
(https://www.dropbox.com/s/xufd736fburdq8a/norm.dat?dl=0)

Comment: You're plotting `data3`, but you're fitting against `datafit`, which doesn't have the x values. If you fit the same dataset that you're plotting, and you make sure the frequency starting value is chosen correctly, it will work.

Comment: The frequency starting value needs to be quite close, by the nature of fitting against an oscillating function. Just today there was another question about that: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/131933/nonlinearfit-with-data

Comment: What Simon said, plus use a Fourier transform to estimate the starting frequency. http://i.stack.imgur.com/VEa8r.png

Comment: Prony's method will handle this sort of example just fine. Though it is probably overkill, given the answer by @MauricioLobos involving a straightforward use of `FindFit`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`FindFit` does an excellent job without any starting values, at least in Mathematica 11

```
file = FileNames["norm.dat", NotebookDirectory[]];
datain = Import[file[[1]]];
model = Cos[a*x]*Exp[b*x];
fit = FindFit[datain, model, {a, b}, x];
plot = Plot[model /. fit, {x, 0, datain[[-1, 1]]}, 
  Epilog -> {Red, Line[datain]}]
```

[image]