# Fitting data with ${\rm sinc}^2(x)$

Tags: fitting, nonlinear

I performed an experiment of Fraunhofer diffraction with slits, the results of which should be proportional to $\operatorname{sinc}^2(x) = \left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)^2$. However, an error occurred when trying to fit the data to the formula.

This is what my data looks like:

[image: Experimental data]

This is my attempt:

```
f3 = NonlinearModelFit[s3, a(Sinc[b (x - ξ)])^2, {{a, 4000}, 
      {b, 1}, {c, 0}, {ξ, 10}}, x]
```

but I get these:

> Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0. encountered.
> Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0.^2 encountered.
> Infinity::indet: Indeterminate expression 0. ComplexInfinity encountered.
> NonlinearModelFit::nrjnum: The Jacobian is not a matrix of real numbers at {a,b,c,ξ} = {4000.,1.,0.,10.}.

I added these initial values {4000, 1, 0, 10} for the parameters after reading [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/131933/nonlinearfit-with-data). I think they should be sufficient for starting points because the model function with these parameters is actually really close:

[image: fit model]

I can't figure out where something like 1/0. could occur. Can someone tell me what to do to make this work?

Comment: Please provide your data too, thanks

Comment: Your fit function does not depend on $c$ and so the optimizer cannot optimize it with respect to $c$. Remove $c$ from the parameter list and try again.

Comment: If your response is a "count", then Poisson regression would likely be better than using `NonlinearModelFit` in that the constant variance assumption of `NonlinearModelFit` is  not appropriate for such data.

Comment: Your function has $x-\xi$ in the denominator.  If one of your predictor values ($x$) happens to be the same as the starting value of $\xi$, then you'll get the error you see.  The same thing will happen if one of the $x$ values equals the current estimated value of $\xi$.  There are several ways to avoid this error.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann The data contains 4000 points, so it's unrealistic to list it all here. Is it possible to upload a txt file? Or maybe I should pick 40 of them?

Comment: @Roman Oh, it's a typo. It was actually $a\operatorname{sinc}^2b(x-\xi)+c$. This didn't work, so I tried removing $c$.

Comment: @JimB The data is actually just the light intensity versus the x coordinate.  Sorry but I can't understand the statistics you mentioned.

Comment: @JimB I thought the MMA function $\operatorname{sinc}x$ is defined at $x = 0$ so that would work.  Could you elaborate on how to circumvent this?

Comment: First, my comment about $x-\xi$ being a problem when $x=\xi$ is wrong because the `Sinc` function takes care of that.  If one used `Sin[x-xi]/(x-xi)`, then there would be an issue.

Comment: The potential issue about lack of constant variance I mentioned is where the variability of the response might be higher with larger values and a smaller amount of variability where the response is closer to zero.  But this is "physics" data and I mainly deal with biological data which seems to have infinitely more variability than "physics" data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `NonlinearModelFit[...,Method->"NMinimize"]`

Examplary `data` (please provide your data)

```
data = Table[{x, Exp[1] (Sinc[Pi (x - 10)])^2}, {x, 0, 20, 1/5}];
f3 = NonlinearModelFit[data, a (Sinc[b (x - \[Xi])])^2, {a, b, \[Xi]},x, Method -> "NMinimize"]  
Show[{Plot[f3[x], {x, 0, 20}, PlotRange -> All],ListPlot[data]}]
```

[image]

Hope it helps!

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much!

Comment: Could you explain why adding "NMinimize" would make this work? Is it because something goes wrong with $\operatorname{sinc}(x)$ when processed symbolically?

Comment: @L0wc3ll No I have no explaination. I only  experienced `NMInimize` to provide robust minimization.

Answer (score 0):

This is just an extended comment (probably more for my benefit than yours).  Does your data (4,000 points) look more like the following:

[image: Data with Poisson variation]

or is it extremely smooth as in the figure you displayed?

I'm trying to understand what should the error structure look like so that it is appropriately incorporated into the analysis.

Comment: It was really smooth, with magnitude of the error at each point below 5. Is there any way I can upload a new picture for you?

Comment: I finally discovered how to edit my question and I've uploaded a new pic.